# How to convert Firebase Array to Swift Array?

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, tuples, firebase-realtime-database

I am reading data from Firebase Data Snapshot which contains an array. 
I was downcasting this snapshot as [String: AnyObject] into a variable say fetchedDict. Now I want to **convert the sensorValues to an swift readable array**. I checked dynamicType of sensorValues

```
print(fetchedDict!["sensorValues"].dynamicType)
```

It is Optional
I have tried two approaches to convert it in array:

1. Downcasting it to NSArray, [Int] but it didnt work.
2. Wrote a mirror function(see at the end) which worked on playground but sadly not in iOS App. It gave me ***Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Array' (0x117a24028) to 'Swift.Int'***.

Can someone please guide me to solve this? Thanks!

```
rootRef!.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects {
            let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
            let fetchedDict = snap.value as? [String: AnyObject]
})
```

This  is the fetchedDict:

```
[
    "activityDuration": 15;
    "sensorValues":   (
        5,
        24,
        24,
        13,
        22,
        4,
        42,
        13,
        3,
        4
    );
    "timestamp": 20160713184023;
]
```

Mirror Function which didnt work in the iOS app. Tried Any as well as AnyObject as argument type. This code works in playground though.

```
func tupleToArray(sensorValues: Any) -> [Int] {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: sensorValues)
    var arr = [Int]()
    for child in mirror.children{
        let stringedValue = (child.value) as! Int
        arr.append(stringedValue)
    }
    return arr
 }
```

Comment: why `child.value`? why not just `child as! Int`?

Comment: does looping through like this work? 
for i in fetchedDict!["sensorValues"] as! Int

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil Tried it too...it gives warning Cast from child to unrelated type 'int' always fails. And when i call the function - Execution was interrupted.

Comment: @jacobbullock no, it doesn't work because it does not conform to protocol seuqenceType.

Comment: @RyanCyrus how are you fetching that dict?  Is that json converting to a dictionary?

Comment: @jacobbullock Yes, I am converting JSON to Dict with
snap.value as? [String: AnyObject]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you just read in as NSArray and then make a Swift array out of it?

Given

```
array_node
  0: "index 0"
  1: "index 1"
  2: "index 2"
```

and to read it

```
    let myRef = self.myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("array_node")
    myRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        let a = snapshot.value as! NSArray
        print(a)

        let b = (a as Array).filter {$0 is String}

        print(b)
    })
```

the output is

```
(
    "index 0",
    "index 1",
    "index 2"
)
[index 0, index 1, index 2]
```

Comment: Yes, I could have.. but i am iterating through all children. But now i realize i can use conditional checking with what you suggested. Thanks! :)